# how to implement Push notifications in Apache Cordova?

Tags: apache, notifications, visual-studio-cordova

I am new to apache cordova apps development.I am working in an App in which i want to implement Push notifications. Which is simple way to do it. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article explaining how to do push notifications [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879353.aspx). A sample associated with that article can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/CordovaNotificationsArticle). Perhaps a bit of a read, but I hope you find it helpful!