# Cordova: how to display system notification?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an application that queries remote server for new messages and receives them as a JSON object. It displays them on screen. Application can work in background mode (using backgroundMode plugin from katzer). When new message arrives, my application plays a chime sound. I also want it to display a message in system tray (or whatever it is called in Android), like "You have XX new messages" so users could tap that message and bring an app to front to read messages. Does anyone know how to do that? I have tried many plugins but nothing worked. Thank you for help! [Screenshot of what I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv8rb.png)

Comment: Thanks for the brief. How are you paying for my development time? PayPal? ;)

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=Notifications%20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement Push notifications in Apache Cordova?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700732/how-to-implement-push-notifications-in-apache-cordova)

Answer (score 0):

I got desired functionality with Cordova-plugin-badge (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge). Additionally, it can display a badge with number of new messages on application icon. However, it didn't work on many launchers (worked well only on Samsung Galaxy for me yet).